# cURL: How to make a login script (with https protocol)?

Tags: curl

Here is a simple login page which works as a login panel for 4shared.com:

```
<form id="login_form" method="post" action="https://www.4shared.com/index.jsp">   
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="login" id="iloginfield">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password here" name="password" id="ipassfield">
    <input type="submit"  value="Login">
</form>
```

It works.
And I thought I could simply run:

```
curl  "http://www.4shared.com/index.jsp" -d "login=xxxxxxx&password=yyyyyyyyyyyyy" -D "/tmp/header.txt"
```

Which should have worked.
But it failed.

Why? How can I make it?

Comment: In what fashion does it fail?  Also, I see that form references an `https://` URL, but you're using `http://`.  Is this for a specific reason?  Does it also fail using the URL reference in the form?

Comment: I found that I've just typed the wrong encoded passphrase... What a shame..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What output are you seeing? You may want to store cookies that the server sends you.

```
   -c/--cookie-jar <file name>
          Specify to which file you want curl to write all cookies after a
          completed  operation.  Curl  writes  all cookies previously read
          from a specified file as  well  as  all  cookies  received  from
          remote server(s). If no cookies are known, no file will be writ‐
          ten. The file will be written using  the  Netscape  cookie  file
          format.  If  you  set  the  file name to a single dash, "-", the
          cookies will be written to stdout.

          NOTE If the cookie jar can't be created or written to, the whole
          curl operation won't fail or even report an error clearly. Using
          -v will get a warning displayed, but that is  the  only  visible
          feedback you get about this possibly lethal situation.

          If  this  option  is used several times, the last specified file
          name will be used.
```